# How to read a value with nested fields in Spark?

Tags: database, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

The dataset I have is riddled with nested fields. For instance the output of  `data.take(1)` gives 9 columns in which the 4th column (c4) has 3 sub-fields and the 1st column of c4 has 3 sub-fields and so on.

The format looks a bit like so

```
[A,B,C,[[d1,d2,d3],D2,D3],E,[F1,[f1,[f21,f22,f23],f3,f4],F3,F4],G,H,I]
```

I would like an array of array data structure (which can be then unrolled to a single array).

Just to make the data look clearer:

```
A
B
C
D
  -D1
    -d1
    -d2
    -d3
  -D2
  -D3
E
F
  -F1
  -F2
    -f1
    -f2
      -f21
      -f22
      -f23
    -f3
    -f4
  -F3
  -F4
G
H
I
```

Of course, I could write a parsing program that would recursively search for sub-fields given a record and generate this tree structure (as an array of arrays). However, I'm hoping there would be a simpler and more efficient pre-built routine in Spark that would handle this in a straight-forward manner.

Any answer in either Spark-Scala or PySpark would be appreciated.

Comment: So, you basically want to know the schema of your dataset/dataframe?

Comment: @addmeaning Yes, yes exactly. In fact, I have the schema as an AVSC file, but I'm not sure how to map the schema to these records as the data is not readily in a JSON format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there are two methods that can help you if you already loaded your dataframe/dataset in memory using spark. Try `df.printSchema()` and `df.schema`, where `df` is a variable referencing your dataset. The first one will print schema on the screen with types of data, the second one will return `StructType` object that can be traversed by your code.

**Update**:

So now you want conveniently select nested field.

Imagine you have following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Question51360175 extends App{
    val session = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("spark-app").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    import session.implicits._

    case class TopLevel(someField: String, nestedLevel: NestedLevel)
    case class NestedLevel(key: Int, value: String)



    val df = Seq(
      TopLevel("first", NestedLevel(1, "Onnu")),
      TopLevel("second", NestedLevel(2, "Rendu"))
    ).toDF

    df.printSchema()

  df.show()
}
```

that will give you this kind of output

```
root
 |-- someField: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nestedLevel: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)

+---------+-----------+
|someField|nestedLevel|
+---------+-----------+
|    first|  [1, Onnu]|
|   second| [2, Rendu]|
+---------+-----------+
```

Now if you want get nested column, for example you only want only `value` column from nested class `NestedLevel` you can just write `df.select("nestedLevel.value").show()` that will return you

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
| Onnu|
|Rendu|
+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. The schema aligns well with the AVSC file I have. However, I'm not sure how to navigate through it. E.g, row(n) gives the nth column, but row(n)(m) throws an error saying Any does not take parameters. How to manipulate the sub-fields?

Comment: I will update my answer.

Comment: Haha just came here and saw the values holding 'Onnu, Rendu' in Tamil. Good to see :-) @addmeaning

Comment: I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51374630/4565943) but it is about traversing a schema. Could you please take a look at it? BTW, nice play with the Tamil numbers.