# How to traverse through a schema in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to iterate over a schema in Spark. Using `df.schema` gives a list of nested `StructType` and `StructFields`.

The root elements can be indexed like so.

```
IN: val temp = df.schema

IN: temp(0)
OUT: StructField(A,StringType,true)

IN: temp(3)
OUT: StructField(D,StructType(StructField(D1,StructType(StructField(D11,StringType,true), StructField(D12,StringType,true), StructField(D13,StringType,true)),true), StructField(D2,StringType,true), StructField(D3,StringType,true)),true)
```

When I try to access the nested `StructType`, the following occurs

```
IN: val temp1 = temp(3).dataType

IN: temp1(0)
OUT:
Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:38: error: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType does not take parameters
       temp1(0)
            ^
StackTrace:
```

What I don't understand is that both `temp` and `temp1` are of the `StructType` class, but `temp` is iterable but `temp1` isn't.

```
IN: temp.getClass
OUT: class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

IN: temp1.getClass
OUT: class org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

I also tried `dtypes` but ended up with the similar problem when trying to access nested elements.

```
IN: df.dtypes(3)(0)
OUT:
Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:36: error: (String, String) does not take parameters
       df.dtypes(3)(0)
                   ^
StackTrace:
```

So, how can you traverse a schema prior to knowing the sub-fields?

Comment: Can you please tell more specifically what you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you getting error in you snippet because you assigned temp1 to `temp(3).dataType` not `temp(3)`. The `dataType` method returns only type of the structure, not structure itself.

Comment: @addmeaning I would like to be able to iterate over the schema structure. In your last answer, I can access each element but only when I knew the exact path of the nested field. However, my dataset holds hundreds of fields of nested data. So, if I can hold my own representation of the schema, I thought it would be easier to traverse the dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want the list of all nested column columns you can write a recursive function like that

**Given:**

```
  val schema = StructType(
    StructField("name", StringType) ::
      StructField("nameSecond", StringType) ::
      StructField("nameDouble", StringType) ::
      StructField("someStruct", StructType(
        StructField("insideS", StringType) ::
          StructField("insideD", StructType(
            StructField("inside1", StringType) :: Nil
          )) ::
          Nil
      )) ::
      Nil
  )
  val rdd = session.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row]
  val df = session.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

 df.printSchema()
```

Which will produce:

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nameSecond: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nameDouble: string (nullable = true)
 |-- someStruct: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- insideS: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- insideD: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- inside1: string (nullable = true)
```

If you want the list of full names of the columns you can write something like this:

```
def fullFlattenSchema(schema: StructType): Seq[String] = {
  def helper(schema: StructType, prefix: String): Seq[String] = {
    val fullName: String => String = name => if (prefix.isEmpty) name else s"$prefix.$name"
    schema.fields.flatMap {
      case StructField(name, inner: StructType, _, _) =>
        fullName(name) +: helper(inner, fullName(name))
      case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Seq(fullName(name))
    }
  }

  helper(schema, "")
}
```

Which will return:

```
ArraySeq(name, nameSecond, nameDouble, someStruct, someStruct.insideS, someStruct.insideD, someStruct.insideD.inside1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I wanted. Currently, your implementation only search up to the second level of nested structures. Could you edit the case functions so that it could do this recursively and list all possible nested levels?

Comment: Can you please let me know what changes i have to make to the code if i have array of struct ?

Comment: @AKC I don't understand, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @addmeaning I have tried your code with below schema . It skipped columns inside array.root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nameSecond: long (nullable = true)
 |-- acctNum: string (nullable = true)
 |-- nameDouble: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- insideK: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- insideS: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- insideD: long (nullable = true)
 |-- inside1: long (nullable = true)

Comment: @AKC can you post your schema on gist.github.com and send the link here, I can't see how your schema differs from original question

Comment: @addmeaning Below is the link.     https://gist.github.com/madhuhad/7b724a1c1ffafa7724f0e9a434123bbd

Comment: @addmeaning How to do the same in pyspark.

Answer (score 3):

In Spark SQL type schemas there are a few complex datatypes to worry about when recursing through it, e.g., StructType, ArrayType and MapType. To write a function that fully traverses a schema with maps of structs and arrays of maps is quite complex.

To recurse down most schemas I have come across, I have only needed to account for StructType and ArrayType.

Given a schema like:

```
    root
     |-- name: string (nullable = true)
     |-- nameSecond: long (nullable = true)
     |-- acctRep: string (nullable = true)
     |-- nameDouble: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- insideK: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- insideS: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |-- insideD: long (nullable = true)
     |-- inside1: long (nullable = true)
```

I would use a recursive function like this:

```
    def collectAllFieldNames(schema: StructType): List[String] = 
        schema.fields.flatMap {
            case StructField(name, structType: StructType, _, _) => name :: collectAllFieldNames(structType)
            case StructField(name, ArrayType(structType: StructType, _), _, _) => name :: collectAllFieldNames(structType)
            case StructField(name, _, _, _) => name :: Nil
        }
```

Giving the result:

```
    List(name, nameSecond, acctRep, nameDouble, insideK, insideS, insideK, inside1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer given by @rich_morton

This would work if we have Struct inside array or Array inside struct nested schema

```
    def flattenSchema(schema: StructType): Seq[String] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap {
    case StructField(name, inner: StructType, _, _) => Seq(name) ++ flattenSchema(inner)
    case StructField(name, ArrayType(structType: StructType, _), _, _) => Seq(name) ++flattenSchema(structType)
    case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Seq(name)
   
  }
}
```

flattenSchema(yourDf.schema)